# Java Loop Chessboard labeling

Tags: java, label, labeling

i want to label my chessboard with A-H at the top and bottom of the board, and 1-8 on the left and right side. This is what my labeling looks like right now:
add(new GLabel("" + ((char) (i + 65) + ""), x, y));
and of course it doesnt label at the top and bottom, its in each tile.
How do I create the letters inside of a loop without showing them in each tile?

This is the whole code of the loop
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {

```
        for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {

            // Calculates the position of the tiles

            double x = j * squareSize + 100;
            double y = i * squareSize + 100;

            // Draws the square

            GRect square = new GRect(x, y, squareSize, squareSize);

            square.setFilled((i + j) % 2 != 0);
            add(square);

            // Labeling the top and bottom with A-H + left and right from 1 to 8
            
                add(new GLabel("" + ((char) (i + 65) + ""), x, y));

                num++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Edit: the if(i <=8 { was just a try. Its not part of the code

Comment: It should be ``if (i < 8)``